# Keras Python Time series analysis

Tags: python, time, keras, analysis, series

I am trying to do time series analysis on the data having two input variables i.e time stamp and no of students. On fitting LSTM model I am getting the following error " Error when checking input: expected lstm_40_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (69452, 1)" on model.fit() . I am new to keras, I am still confused how to fit the model. My data is in form (69452,1,1) i.e. a three dimentional vector.

**Following is the code:**

```
trainX, trainY = createDataSet(train)
testX, testY = createDataSet(test)

trainY=trainY.reshape(69452,1) 
testY=testY.reshape(140,1)

trainX=trainX.reshape(69452,1)
testX=testX.reshape(140,1)


xTrain = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0],1, trainX.shape[1]))

xTest = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))

yTrain = np.reshape(trainY, (trainY.shape[0],1, trainY.shape[1]))

yTest = np.reshape(testY, (testY.shape[0], 1, testY.shape[1]))

yTrain = np.reshape(trainY, (trainY.shape[0], 1, trainY.shape[1]))

yTest = np.reshape(testY, (testY.shape[0], 1, testY.shape[1]))


model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))

model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(xTrain , yTrain , epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

Comment: Your not really doing time series if you have 2 and third dimension equal to one

Comment: Thanks man for your help. Actually the issue is at my end, I apologize for that